# Let $G,H$ be cyclic groups. Find $u,v \in K := G \times H $ such that $o(u) =4, o(v) =5. $

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

Let $G = \left \langle {g} \right \rangle, H =\left \langle {h} \right \rangle$ be multiplicative cyclic groups of order $4$ and $5$ respectively. 
Let $K:= G \times H $  and define binary operation $*$ on $K$ by $(x_1,y_1)*(x_2,y_2) = (x_1y_1, x_2y_2)$$, \forall (x_1,y_1),(x_2, y_2) \in K.$ Find  $u,v \in K$ such that $o(u) =4, o(v) =5. $

My proof:

Let $e_G, e_H$ be identity elements of $G $ and $H$ respectively.

Let $u = (g^i, h^j)\in G \times H.$

$o(u) = 4 $

$\implies(g^i)^4 = e_G\wedge (h^j)^4  =e_H $

$\implies $ $i =1,2,3,4$ $ \wedge j=5$ since $(h^j)^4 \neq e_H, j=1,2,3,4. $

Now, if $u = (g^i, e_H), $ then $o(u) = 4, $ for $i=1,3.$ ( since $o(g) = o(g^3) =4)$

Let $v = (g^n, h^m) \in G\times H. $

$o(v) =5 $

$\implies (g^n)^5 =e_G \wedge (h^m)^5 =e_H $

$\implies n = 4$ since $(g^n)^5 \neq e_H, n=1,2,3 \wedge m =1,2,3,4,5$

Now, if $v =(e_G, h^m),$ then $o(v) =5,$ for $m =1,2,3,4$ (since $o(h)=...=o(h^4) =5)$

However, I'm told that my proof is wrong. May I know what is amiss? Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps the grader does not like that the answer is verbose.  All you really need to do is exhibit two elements of $K$ (for example $u = (g, e_H)$ and $v = (e_G, h)$) and show that they have the necessary orders.  You seem to be starting with an arbitrary element of $K$ and showing what form it has to be in, which is arguably more difficult. I don't see anything fundamentally wrong with your answer, though.

Comment: There could be the point that you don't explain what you're doing. To the unsuspecting viewer, it might seem you're assuming what's to be proven, rather than exhibiting your thought process. If you said you were going to find a necessary condition, and only then verify that it indeed suffices as well, it might go down smoother.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing amiss in your proof, but it is a rather round-about way to arrive at your the elements $u, v$. The problem statement asks you only to "find" some $u, v$ satisfying $o(u) = 4, o(v) = 5$.  It might also have been prudent to have added a bit more in the way of explanation (that you were finding necessary conditions on $u, v$, first, then showing these are sufficient conditions too, e.g.).

I do not, however, believe your answer is therefore "wrong." Usually students are not penalized for doing more than what is required.